# What does JsonFormatter.MaxDepth do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

What does the MaxDepth property effect in the JsonMediaTypeFormatter?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter.maxdepth(v=vs.108).aspx

Changing this in my WebApiConfig doesn't seem to effect anything.

Comment: I would assume limit the amount of nesting in JSON objects, if you set it to something like 1 everything still works the same?

Comment: That was my guess too.  I had a self-referencing loop and set MaxDepth to 1 but did not see any effect.

Comment: Looking at the code for that class it looks like it just passes it along to JsonTextReader as a param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MaxDepth property is internal passed to the JsonTextReader class in the `ReadFromStreamAsync` method

https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs

According to the JsonTextReader parent class's docs, this property is 
*"Gets or sets the maximum depth allowed when reading JSON. Reading past this depth will throw a JsonReaderException. "*

http://datasift.github.io/datasift-dotnet/d1/dd6/classNewtonsoft_1_1Json_1_1JsonReader.html